# Can someone help ? I have this answer of linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

[image]
Onto?
What we have in class that if $n=2$ and $m=3$ that clear $2<3$ ,$T$ will be not onto.
He said make three point u have with three variable $=(y,z)$ .then u will have one free variable that will be expressed by $x_1,x_2,x_3$...
I do it $x_1$ will free variable but I get very complicated answer,and does the question mean what the condition to be onto or 1-1? 
last answer i have i do not make sure can some one help 
[image]

Comment: Of course $T$ can be onto; perhaps you're confusing the definition of "onto" with "one-to-one." This problem can be solved by finding the matrix for $T$ and applying row reduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $b_1,b_2\in\Bbb R$, the equations
$$x_1+2x_2+3x_3=b_1\ ,\quad -x_1-4x_3=b_2$$
always have a solution.  Therefore $T$ is onto.

Comment: can u please see the answer is it correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me, well done!